# Facebook PHP how to know who uploaded the image?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created an app to enable users to upload their images from my website onto my facebook page. We recently created a competition where people had to upload their picture and which ever picture gets most likes win. The app is still being built. The app is being built using PHP.

From my research tagging someone in photo captions has been disabled (unless my resources are incorrect).

How can we know who uploaded which picture please? To know who won?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make a Graph API / FQL call to one of the photos and get the id of the user who uploaded this.

Try this FQL in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer):

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, app_id, target_id, message, attachment, likes FROM stream 
 WHERE filter_key = 'others' AND source_id = 'YOUR_PAGE_ID' AND app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID'
  AND attachment.fb_object_type = 'photo'
```

The `actor_id` field should be the person who uploaded the image.

You could add `ORDER BY likes.count DESC`to the end of this to sort this by likes. You'll need to do a little more massaging to make sure you're returning all the items eligible for the contest.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am still a newbie. How can I integrate your code with this - in PHP - `$args = array(
   'message'=> "Uploaded Photo",
   'image' => '@' . $img,`

Thanks

Comment: The best way is via the PHP SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ Pass the FQL query via the `api` method. You'll get an associative array back with all your data. Dump this with `print_r` and you'll see the structure of this. To get this information, you need to authenticate. The easiest way for something like this is to create a "connector" app on Facebook that only your script will use and use this app's token and secret.

Comment: I am sorry but it is too complicated. Sorry for being too cheeky but I am still a novice. My site already has the PHP SDK how do the remaining please.